# User model: username format method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, format

Ok, so in my user model i have created get_username in an attempt to format the username.

The idea is to be able to use

```
TheUser.get_username
```

and it would correctly format the username based on user level (admin). As a test I created this:

```
  def get_username 
    fname = '<span style="color:red">John</span>'
    fname
  end
```

However, it displayed the value literally with the code showing..

How would i be able to plug the username in as well as display correctly

Comment: html_safe is not accessible in models, implement this get_username in a helper

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`html_safe`](http://yehudakatz.com/2010/02/01/safebuffers-and-rails-3-0/).

```
 def get_username 
   fname = '<span style="color:red">John</span>'
   fname.html_safe
 end
```

---

To get the user_name use:

```
def get_username 
  fname = "<span style='color:red'>#{user_name}</span>"
  fname.html_safe
end
```

Note that this is very bad code, not only is this abusing the seperation of responsibilty of MVC it also may introduce security vulernabilities.

Code like this should be in view or a helper.

Comment: Thanks got that wporking. How would i be able to now add the username into the string in replacement of John

Answer (score 0):

The Model is not supposed to create the html. You do that in the views. May I suggest another approach instead:

I suppose, you got some variable to store the `user_level`. Use this in the view like so:

```
# .ERB-File
<span class="<%= user.user_level %>"><%= user.user_name %></span>
```

Now format it with css:

```
# .css-File
span.normal_user {
  color: green;
}
span.admin {
  color: red;
}
```

PS: I'm not sure about the ERB-Syntax (I use haml).

Comment: The idea behind this was to have a centralised place to set the name formatting as it would need to be edited in future

Comment: A central place to do the name formatting would be the css file, no?

Comment: the name formatting will most likely change in the future, such as icons may be displayed next to the name based on any number of values